# How to install Ganglia on CentOS 5.4 64 bit?

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, centos5, ganglia

In my case it's running on EC2 Compute Cluster HVM instance, so it should use TCP instead of UDP.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jansipke.nl/installing-ganglia-on-centos